# Prevent Eclipse autocomplete from adding asterisk, star, wildcard to the end of import

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

In Eclipse, while selecting an import package using the autocomplete feature, e.g. **import org.springframework**, it automatically adds an asterisk (the star, wildcard) to the end whereas I'd like to keep on adding some other subpackage e.g. **org.springframework.stereotype**

How can I prevent Eclipse adding an asterisk to the end?

This question has been already been asked at SO question #35089078 but no conclusive answer has been given.

Comment: What setting do you have in _Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Organize Imports_ for _Number of imports needed for `.*` (e.g. `org.eclipse.*`)_?

Comment: It's 99 and the line below it, namely  Number of static imports needed for .* is too 99. They're defaults. I haven't touched any setting to fix this problem.

Comment: Then it should actually work. Do you use the latest version of Eclipse (2018-09)? Are you sure you don't have project-specific settings that override this?

Comment: It's the April 2018 version. No override has been done, just created a new project without touching any such options. Maybe I'm pressing the wrong butons: I spress ctrl+space then select the package name and enter. Maybe there's a particular combination of buttons for this which I don't know.

Comment: When typing `import java.n` the autocompetion offers me the package `java.nio`, but also subpackages like `java.nio.charset`. Of course, only the packages that are on the classpath are proposed. Do you use JPMS (do you have a `module-info.java` file)?